# Writing a service object that returns JSON only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3, hash

I'm trying to write a service object, called `JSONDocument`, that returns only JSON out of several conditions and the like. So far it looks like this:

```
# encoding: utf-8
#
class JSONDocument
  attr_reader :components, :cover, :introduction, :photo, :title, :user, :variables

  def initialize(document)
    @document = document
    components if @document.template.component_count > 0
  end

  private

  def user
    if @document.ap?
      self[:user] = @document.ap_info.gsub("\r\n", "\n")
    else
      self[:user] = @document.no_ap.gsub("\r\n", "\n")
    end
  end

  def variables
    u = []
    @document.template_variables.each do |v|
      u << v.heading_and_body
    end
    u
  end

  def extension(file)
    File.extname(file)
  end

  def components
    components = []
    @document.publications.rank(:position).each do |p|
      components << { component_id: p.component.id,
                      component_page_count: p.component.page_count || 1 }
    end
    self << components
  end

  def cover
    if @document.template.has_covers?
      self[:cover] = "#{@document.cover.id}#{extension(@document.cover.cover_file_name)}"
    else
      self[:cover] = ''
    end
  end

  def introduction
    if @document.template.has_introductions?
      self[:introduction] = message.gsub("\r\n\r\n", "\r\n")
    else
      self[:introduction] = ''
    end
  end

  def photo
    if @document.photo
      self[:photo] = "#{@document.photo.id}#{extension(@document.photo.photo_file_name)}"
    else
      self[:photo] = ''
    end
  end

  def title
    @document.template.has_title ? self[:title] = title : self[:title] = ''
  end
end
```

But I'm not really sure how to add elements to the object to access the information like so:

```
json = JSONDocument.new(@document)
json[:title] => 'Some title of @document'
```

Any help would be fantastic. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a method simulating the hash access style like this:

```
def [](key)
  raise "An error occurred" if ... #some validation to filter trash
  self.send(key)
end
```

Of course it will only provide access to your object's attributes (get but not set).

Comment: But, for added complexity, what if I wanted the object to return the hash built of out the attributes listed above, and not just one at a time?

Comment: I wrote this:
`def to_hash
  {}.tap do |h|
    @@attributes.each { |k, v| h[k.to_sym] = self.send(k) }
  end
end`

Comment: It's not dynamic. Every new attr created means you have to change the array of attributes.

Comment: If you're gonna need more features like these, just use a OpenStruct: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html

Comment: No, it's not, which is a little bit annoying, but in this case it can't be totally dynamic. Plus, I've no idea how to implement that `OpenStruct`.